# Passing class and its function into another class

Tags: python, oop

I'm looking to pass a class and it's methods into a class. I have no problem with passing the class as it's accessible during instance initiation but the methods (when passed separately) are not.

The non-functional example is simplified a lot and only the classes Caller and Callable could be modified, the initial call should remain unmodified. I would prefer to not go with exec or eval if at all possible.

```
class Caller(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Caller, self).__init__()
        self.klass = kwargs.get('klass', None)
        self.func = kwargs.get('func', None)
        self.klassParams = kwargs.get('klassParams', None)

    def call(self):
        klass = self.klass(**self.klassParams)

        # Call the function
        someFunc = self.func
        klass.someFunc()

class Callable(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Callable, self).__init__()

    def someFunction():
        pass

c = Caller(klass=Callable, func=someFunction, klassParams={'some':'param'})
c.call()
```

This will obviously fail with `NameError: name 'someFunction' is not defined`

Comment: Not sure about what you're trying to implement but  `Callable.someFunction` should get rid of that error.

Comment: Right but what I'm using, the object generation and initial call cannot be modified, meaning both the class and the function have to be passed separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getattr` bulit in function in python, here is how you can use it,

## getattr(object, name[, default])

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a
>   string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
>   the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x,
>   'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not
>   exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is
>   raised.

I have made quite a few corrections to your code, so now the code will work fine,

```
class Caller(object):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        # Calling object class constructor doesn't take the argument name parent as its the base class in python
        super(Caller, self).__init__()
        self.klass = kwargs.get('klass', None)
        self.func = kwargs.get('func', None)
        self.klassParams = kwargs.get('klassParams', None)

    def call(self):
        klass = self.klass(**self.klassParams)

        # Call the function
        someFunc = self.func
        getattr(klass, someFunc)()

class Callable(object):
    def __init__(self, some=None, parent=None):
        # Calling object class constructor doesn't take the argument name parent as its the base class in python
        super(Callable, self).__init__()

    def someFunction(self):
        print("someFunction called by Caller")
        pass

# You have to pass the string representating the name of function to be called, in this case pass `'someFunction'`    
c = Caller(klass=Callable, func='someFunction', klassParams={'some':'param'})
c.call()
```

The output will be,

```
someFunction called by Caller
```

Comment: Makes sense and I was pondering a similar approach. I was thinking if there's more obvious solution that I was missing.

Comment: I think `getattr` is the simplest way by which you could access the named attribute/method inside the given class.

Comment: Also, you dont need to call the `object` constructor explicitly in your code its called implicitly by the intrepreter.

Comment: I'm also curious how would I pass an argument into said function.

Comment: Answering my own question, it's obviously getattr(klass, someFunc)('arg')